# displaying parsed string into view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie to angular js. from web API I receive the title as "**color_flower**"
in my view I am trying to display it as "**Color Flower**"
Could any one know how to do this in angularjs. I have tried with Angular filters but no luck!!

Comment: Update your text in controller before you set in $scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
var txt = "color_flower_pink".replace(/[^_]+/g, function(a){
   return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1)
}).replace(/_+/g," ");

document.write(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller

```
  var title = "color_flower";
  title = title.split('_');

  function firstChartToUpper (str) {
    return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
  }
  $scope.title = firstChartToUpper(title[0]) + " " + firstChartToUpper(title[1]);
```

**Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/7cbNJjes4DINlY2reph8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Shankar..Its work..But if the title is an array with varying string length containing multiple strings how to parse it.

Comment: If the `title` is an array then you just have to run the above code in a loop for each item in the array.